# Question 36 of chapter 16 from Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Gallian

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $\phi$ be the ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ given by $\phi(f(x)) = f(1)$. Find a polynomial $g(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that  $\ker \phi=\left<g(x)\right>$. To what ring is  $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\ker\phi$ isomorphic?

I tried in the following way

$g(x) = x-1$ satisfies $\ker \phi$

I know that first theorem of ring homomorphism says that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\ker \phi$ is isomorphic to $\phi(\mathbb{Z}[x])$ but I don't know how do I proceed further.

Comment: For the other direction, use polynomial division and the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a UFD.

Comment: You have to prove that any polynomial in $\ker\phi$ is divisible by $x-1$. Then notice that the image of $\phi$ is $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you know that $\ker \phi = \langle x-1 \rangle$ and that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\ker \phi$ is isomorphic to $\phi(\mathbb{Z}[x])$. But $\phi$ is surjective since the constant polynomials $p_n(x) = n$ are mapped by $\phi$ to $n \in \mathbb Z$. Thus  $\phi(\mathbb{Z}[x]) = \mathbb Z$.

**Edited:**

To show that $\ker \phi = \langle x-1 \rangle$ observe that $f(x) \in \ker \phi$ iff $f(1) = 0$, i.e. $f$ has a zero at $x = 1$. It is well-known that then $f(x) = g(x) \cdot (x-1)$ for some polynomial $g(x)$ (use polynomial long division). Thus $\ker \phi = \langle x-1 \rangle$.